# laravel eloquent hasmany relation returns when one row required

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

there are lots of questions in this area, but I can't quite find one that fits. I think it's very basic Laravel understanding.

I have a simple relationship set up between 'properties' and 'images'. For a particular mapping view, I need to get the property data, along with the file name of the 'lead' image. So, I only ever need one image result, according to whether the image is marked '1' as being the lead image in the DB.

Controller code looks like this:

```
if(Input::get('m') == 'true'){
            //$map_data = Property::all();

            $map_data = Property::with(array('images' => function($query)
            {
                //just grab the lead image to put in the marker popups.
                $query->where('is_lead', 1)->first();

            }))->get();


            return View::make('property_map')->with('data', $map_data);
        }
```

But in the view, the only way I can get this to work is with a foreach loop, even though I only ever want one result:

```
@foreach($property->images as $image)
  {{$image->filename}}
@endforeach
```

Which is obviously daft.  I think I'm just missing something simple with that loop in the view, but I may have misunderstood how to address this in the controller too. Think I've read the laravel docs about 20 times now, just can't quite get this little detail. Thanks.

UPDATE - I've just had another go at this, and managed to get rid of the pointless foreach by doing this in the view:

```
$property->images->first()["filename"]
```

.. but this still doesn't feel very 'laravel' .. would still appreciate any thoughts on a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `->get()` to `->first()`.

```
if(Input::get('m') == 'true'){
            //$map_data = Property::all();

            $map_data = Property::with(array('images' => function($query)
            {
                //just grab the lead image to put in the marker popups.
                $query->where('is_lead', 1)->first();

            }))->first();


            return View::make('property_map')->with('data', $map_data);
        }
```

Comment: I think that would just give me one property, whereas I need all the properties, with each just having the one related image.